# vb.net tryparse result variable scope

Tags: vb.net, scope, tryparse

I'm not content with the way tryparse requires you to declare the output variable ahead of time, since the scope for that varible is too broad. Is there a better way to handle these situations?

First example:

```
Dim tempDate As Date
If Date.TryParse(TextBox08.Text, tempDate) Then
    MonthCalendar1.SetDate(tempDate)
End If
' This code is just a part of a larger function.
' I don't need to use the tempDate in the block where it is declared.
' I only need it inside the if statement and if block.
```

Second example:

```
If Date.TryParse(TextBox08.Text, Nothing) Then
    MonthCalendar1.SetDate(Date.Parse(TextBox08.Text))
End If
' Now I'm parsing the textbox twice . . .
```

Third examples:

```
If Date.TryParse(TextBox08.Text, tempDate) Then
    Dim tempDate As Date
    MonthCalendar1.SetDate(tempDate)
End If

' Or

If Date.TryParse(TextBox08.Text, Dim tempDate As Date) Then
    MonthCalendar1.SetDate(tempDate)
End If
' These would be ideal, but of course they don't compile.
```

Am I digging too deep here? Maybe the compiler fixes this sort of problem on it's own? I just feel like I'm writing inefficient code either way I decide to handle this.

### Edit 1:

If I were to adapt jh00ker's suggestion to my situation my code would look like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox08_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox08.GotFocus
    'Some Code
    Call SetMonthCalendar()
    'More Code
End Sub

Private Sub SetMonthCalendar()
    Dim tempDate As Date
    If Date.TryParse(TextBox08.Text, tempDate) Then
        MonthCalendar1.SetDate(tempDate)
    End If
End Sub
```

Does this seem reasonable? It accomplishes what I wanted, but it almost seems like the solution is more complicated than the problem.

Comment: A local variable, declared and used for a perfectly valid reason, is hardly a symptom of inefficiency.

Comment: @Steve I'm not upset so much about the existence of the local variable as it's placement in the code, and therefore it's scope. Why should every part of the larger function have access to a variable that is only used with a single if block? That's the part I'm seeing as inefficient. Though I interpret your comment as "Yes, I'm digging too deep."

Comment: Yes probably you are really digging to search something that doesn't exist. Perhaps, if you have a very big function it is better to dedicate some effort to split it in smaller logical pieces also if you call these subs just one time. Comment each sub appropriately for your future reference and the _problem_ of this variable will be naturally removed

Answer (score 0):

Steve is right, there's nothing wrong with declaring a variable to do work.  Parsing a string into a date variable is legitimate work.  Garbage collection will handle the rest.

The only alternative I can think of is something like the code below, which actually could be confusing to another developer looking at your code in the future.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If SetMonthCalendar(TextBox1.Text, MonthCalendar1) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Bad Date")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function SetMonthCalendar(value As String, calendar As MonthCalendar) As Boolean
    Dim tempDate As Date
    If Date.TryParse(value, tempDate) Then
        calendar.SetDate(tempDate)
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I considered a subroutine that isolates the local variable from the rest of the function, but wasn't sure if it was worthwhile, since changing the scope of the variable would be the only reason for the new method. I don't intend to do anything at all if the TryParse fails, so in my case I wouldn't bother with another if statement to catch the error in the Button1_Click method.